# How to Insert Text in FabricJS v2?

Tags: fabricjs

The insertChars function doesn't exist anymore in version 2.
Any idea how to insert text programmatically into the textbox element?

http://jsfiddle.net/redlive/jvuvm2qg/

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('paper');
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(500);

var text = new fabric.Textbox('Heo world', {
  left: 50,
  top: 10,
  fontFamily: 'arial',
  fill: '#333',
  fontSize: 50
});

canvas.add(text);

const style = {
 textBackgroundColor: 'red'
};

const chars = "ll", selectionStart = 2;

//Need help with the function, since it doesn't exists anymore
text.insertChars(chars, selectionStart, style);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

canvas.renderAll();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.0.0-rc.3/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="paper" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #ccc"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to separate inserting and styling of chars like this:

```
text.insertChars(chars, null, selectionStart);

text.setSelectionStyles(style, selectionStart, selectionStart + chars.length);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6wzLb2cL/